# How can I set Main Page (or wait for MainThread) if app is closed during the startup process?

Tags: multithreading, xamarin.forms, ui-thread, android-runonuithread

When my app is launched, a splash screen is set which is just an `ActivityIndicator`. Then, a task is run that starts up services and looks for saved passwords. This task is run async so the `ActivityIndicator` can spin. This works ok unless the home button (Android) is pressed while this task is running. I know it is because if the app is closed, the main thread is not accessible. But what I do not know is how I could solve this. I will post App.xaml.cs below.

```
    public App()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        MainPage = new SplashScreen();

        app = this;
    }

    protected override async void OnStart()
    {
        base.OnStart();
        await StartupAsync();
    }

    private async Task StartupAsync()
    {
        ServiceRegistrator.Startup();

        MessagingCenter.Subscribe<NavigationMenuMasterDetailPage>(this, MessagingServiceConstants.LOGOUT, (sender) =>
        {
            Logout();
        });

        var assemblyType = typeof(App).GetTypeInfo();

        AutoFac.Builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(assemblyType.Assembly)
            .Where(t => t.Name.EndsWith("Service"))
            .AsImplementedInterfaces()
            .SingleInstance();

        _keyChainHelper = AutoFac.Container.Resolve<IKeyChainHelper>();

        TextResources.Culture = DependencyService.Get<ILocalize>().GetCurrentCultureInfo();

        var hasCredentials = HasKeyInChainstore("username") && HasKeyInChainstore("password");

        if (hasCredentials)
        {
            await Task.Run(() =>
            {
                var logonService = AutoFac.Container.Resolve<ILogonService>();
                var username = _keyChainHelper.GetKey("username");
                var password = _keyChainHelper.GetKey("password");
                logonService.Logon(username, password);
            });

            Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
            {
                MainPage = new NavigationMenuMasterDetailPage();
            });
        }
        else
        {
            Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
            {
                ShowLoginPage();
            });
        }
    }
```

I know there must be something to do to either wait for the main thread to be available, or force the app to open again. The exact exception is "java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState" and this occurs at the `Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread()`.